# docker git clone during build is not cloning (and not erroring)

Tags: git, docker

Here is the docker git command

```
  WORKDIR /var/www
  RUN git clone --verbose git@github.com:<private git repo>.git /var/www
```

The git clone command executes without error but after attaching to the container I can't find the project in any of the folders. I've tried to cd into /var/www before the clone but same result. One odd thing, I expected the the --verbose flag to output the summary details of the project but it does not. So I added a statement to verify the ssh connection:

```
  RUN \
    chmod 600 /repo-key && \  
    echo "IdentityFile /repo-key" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config && \
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config && \
    ssh -v git@github.com
```

It connects successfully, the output:

```
  Hi willlopez! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
  debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
  debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  Transferred: sent 2944, received 1464 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
  Bytes per second: sent 31103.1, received 15467.0
  debug1: Exit status 1
```

The git clone output:

```
  Cloning into '/var/www'...
  Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address to the list of known hosts.
```

I used nsenter docker-enter to attach to the running container. /var/www is empty

Comment: is /var/www declared as a volume?

Comment: @AdrianMouat yes it is

Comment: It needs to be a "working" directory so the developer can make changes to the project, verify the changes and check it back into git

Comment: Ok, that's the problem. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `git clone` is working fine, but as `/var/www` is a volume, the changes are being thrown away. After a volume is declared in a `Dockerfile`, you can't make changes to that directory; remember volumes are set up at run time.

If you move the `VOLUME` statement after the git clone statement, it will copy the files into the volume. If you can't do that, you could execute the clone at run time in a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` script.

For more information on volumes, see the official Docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/ or this blog http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: Thank you @AdrianMouat. I removed the volume from the run command and can see the git project now. I'll need to better understand how volume works because I clearly don't. Not sure if it's murkier because I'm using boot2docker and not on a "pure" linux box.

Comment: BTW, the volume command in the dockerfile is one of the last commands, after the git clone command. Has to be my run command that is faulty

Answer (score 1):

The error is a part of the test.   You're authenticating to GitHub fine.

```
Hi MakotoTheKnight! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3632, received 1800 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 27200.9, received 13480.6
debug1: Exit status 1
```

That said, whenever you do `git clone`, whatever path you have specified for your private Git repo, Git uses that directory by default.  It can be overridden by providing a follow-up argument specifying the directory you want to place your code into (e.g. `git clone git@github.com:UserName/someproject.git somedirectory`.

If you have write permissions into the directory, your code contents *should* be in there.
 You can verify the permissions via `ls -l`, and if you're the user who owns or are in the same group as the user who owns `/var/www`, it should work.

Comment: +Makoto I tried that but still nothing. I updated the post. Thank you